# unable to stream mp4 on galaxy nexus jelly bean

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i'm having trouble trying to find a video player to play a stream for my app on a galaxy nexus.

it works on every other phone apart from nexus.

if i dont give the app the tag to tell it that it's a video in the url it gives me an options screen to choose what to complete the action with, in this list it doesn't show a video player. (if i state that it is a video i get a class not found exception)

anyone know what the issue is? as i said it's working on other phones apart from nexus, even works on galaxy s3

thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat information that is output after you get the classnotfound exception?

Also, are you running a rom that is customized to that device? It's possible that an issue may reside there

Comment: standard rom. what ever they pushed with their jelly bean update a few months back.

Comment: Okay, can you provide the logcat after the crash takes place? That will help us to narrow down your issue